# How can I remove bookmarks from an OpenXML docx file?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I thought the following would work:

```
var bod = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

foreach (var bookmark in bod.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
{
    bookmark.Remove();
}

foreach (var bookmark in bod.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>())
{
    bookmark.Remove();
}
```

but this corrupts the file.

Comment: Note: you cannot modify a collection that you're iterating which appears to be what you're doing here. Also you could you explain **HOW** it corrupts the document?

Comment: I don't know how the document is corrupted, only that it is. It's an error message I get from Word when I try to open it. It doesn't provide any more information.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it worked on my document.

```
var bs = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document
             .Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
             .ToList();
        foreach (var s in bs)
            s.Remove();

var be = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document
             .Descendants<BookmarkEnd>()
             .ToList();
        foreach (var e in be)
            e.Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

> bookmark.RemoveAllChildren();

before

> bookmark.Remove()

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.RemoveAllChildren<BookmarkStart>();
wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.RemoveAllChildren<BookmarkEnd>();
```